# No logro obtener los datos del ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

Estoy tratando de obtener los datos con el *for* ya que son varios array pero no logro obtener nada, los datos que quiero obtener pues son la ciudad, el país etc... qué puedo estar haciendo mal?

```js
// CONSULTA
$.ajax({
      url: "https://api.geocodify.com/v2/autocomplete?api_key=0000&q=" + this.value,
      type: "GET",
      success: function(location) {

        for (var i = 0; i < location.length; i++) {
        
        country.innerText = location[i].country;
        
        }


      }

});
```

**DATOS OBTENIDOS**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Según se aprecia, el atributo `country` se encuentra dentro de otro (supongo que es `properties`) al cual no estás accediendo.

Comment: Puedes incluir el `JSON` de la respuesta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buenas tardes para obtener el país deberías acceder de la siguiente manera:

```
let myQuery = "arepa" // use una variable para mantener dinámica la url

fetch(
  "https://api.geocodify.com/v2/autocomplete?api_key=AQUI_VA_TU_API_KEY="+myQuery
)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((location) => {
    
    const arrayRecibido = location.response.features;

    for (const elem of arrayRecibido) {
      console.log(elem.properties.country +" "+ elem.properties.locality +" "+ elem.properties.region);
      //country.innerText = element.properties.country;
    }
  });
```

Fetch es nativo de javascript, se puede hacer la llamada con Ajax también.